# Error opening socket ssl://api.nodesquirrel.com:443

Tags: 7, migrations, backups

I am using Backup and Migrate on D7. I am unable to backup to NodeSquirrel due to the following error:

```
TYPE    backup_migrate

The NodeSquirrel server returned the following error: Error opening socket ssl://api.nodesquirrel.com:443

Could not run backup because the file could not be saved to the destination.
```

Please see below a screenshot of the error-

[image]

*Apparently, it is a bug with the `Backup and Migrate` module as mentioned in the answer.*

Comment: I would appreciate it more if people who are downvoting the post can mention their comment/suggestion to do so...

Comment: Apparently, it is a bug with the `Backup and Migrate` module as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate/issues/3037038

> Update April 10: Workaround
>
> Per e5sego, the "nodesquirrel_default_endpoint_urls" variable can be changed to "74.121.199.90/services/xmlrpc" to avoid the current DNS problems we're seeing, e.g.
> drush vset nodesquirrel_default_endpoint_urls "74.121.199.90/services/xmlrpc"
> Just make sure to delete the variable once the DNS problems are resolved (drush vdel nodesquirrel_default_endpoint_urls).

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I don't have `drush` installed since the website is running on shared hosting. Can you tell me any alternative to achieve the same, please?

Comment: I edited `_get_endpoints` function inside `backup_migrate/includes/destinations.nodesquirrel.inc` file. I commented line number 824 and added the following line `$servers = array('74.121.199.90/services/xmlrpc');` I also replaced `api.nodesquirrel.com:` with `74.121.199.90` inside the same function.